# Unit tests not seeing new version of managed object model

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data

I've created a new version of my managed object model (new xcdatamodel file), updated the xcdatamodeld to have the new version as "current", and added a attribute (hasStartWithFlow) to an entity (Cycle).  hasStartWithFlow is Boolean, not Optional, Default=NO.  I've updated Cycle.h to have

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasStartWithFlow;
```

and Cycle.m to have

```
@dynamic startsWithFlow;
```

I instantiate a new persistent store file (sqlite) in the unit testing code, and then try to set the new value:

```
    cycle.startsWithFlow = true;
```

I get the error `-[Cycle setStartsWithFlow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x192ebf0`.  If I break the unit test execution and examine `[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cycle" inManagedObjectContext:context]`, I see that it does not include my new attribute.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hm.  ./Xcode/DerivedData/<wkspc-guid>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppNameLogicTests.octest/DataModel.momd/VersionInfo.plist still has NSManagedObjectModel_CurrentVersionName pointing to the old version, even though it says the file was updated when I did my last build.  Deleting the DataModel.momd directory in the octest package just results in the wrong value being recreated.  Hm.

Comment: Sounds like maybe when you updated the model, you only updated settings for your main app target, not for the unit test target.

Comment: How could I do that?  There's one xcdatamodeld source file with target membership checked for both targets.  I only see one place to set currentVersion (under "Versioned Core Data Model" in the File Inspector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this really explains what was wrong, but restarting Xcode solved my problem.